# Matlab quantize the hue and saturation of image into bins

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Is there any way to quantize the Hue, Saturation, and Value of an image into bins?
I want to quantize the Hue into 20 bins, Saturation and Value into 8 bins each.

After that, I want to calculate the number of Hue in each bins, as well as the saturation and value.

Comment: You mean like [histcounts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html)?

Comment: The dynamic range of HSV in MATLAB after you use `rgb2hsv` spans `[0,1]` for all channels.  Use that and divide up each channel into the right number of bins, then use `histcounts` as beaker suggested.

Comment: Hi beaker, Hi rayryeng, may I ask, after using [N,edges], what are N and what are edges? N is the number of Hue count in the specific bin right? But what are the use of the bin's edges?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your image into `hsv` using [`rgb2hsv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2hsv.html)

```
hsv_im = rgb2hsv( rgb_im );
```

Now you can define a colormap in HSV space that represents your quantized bins' centers

```
dh = 1/20; %// bin for Hue
dsv = 1/8; %// bin for saturation/value
[Q{1:3}] = meshgrid((dh/2):dh:1, (dsv/2):dsv:1, (dsv/2):dsv:1 ); 
Q = [Q{1}(:) Q{2}(:) Q{3}(:)]; %// quant color map
```

Once you have the color map you can use [`rgb2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html) to quantize your image according to `Q`:

```
q_img = rgb2ind( hsv_im, Q, 'nodither' );
```

Comment: Sorry, but why do you need to divide dh & dsv by 2?

[Q{1:3}] = meshgrid((dh/2):dh:1, (dsv/2):dsv:1, (dsv/2):dsv:1 );

Comment: @StephanieWong because you want the bins' centers

Comment: Hi Shai, I am getting this error:
Error in rgb2ind>parse_inputs (line 146)
if any(m(:)<0)

Error in rgb2ind (line 49)
[RGB,m,dith] = parse_inputs(varargin{:});

Error in SVMTrain (line 66)
                quantizedImg = rgb2ind( imgHsv, Q, 'nodither' );